# How to evaluate script tags when loading a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar and whenever a user clicks on a link, the container gets loaded with the respective file.

For example:

HTML

```
<a href="home.php" class = "navLink">Home</a>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $(".navLink").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".container").load(this.href);
    });
});
```

Sample HTML:

```
<p>Test</p>
<script>        
    var a = new Date(2015,7,1,0,0,0) - new Date();
    var b = Math.round((a/1000) - 2592000);                 
    var timer = new Countdown({time:b, style: "flip", rangeHi: "days", height: 60, width: 415});
</script>
<p>Test</p>
```

However one of my files has `<script></script>` tags. When I load this page, it doesn't work correctly. It doesn't display in the container but rather opens the file directly. Also, only the script tag runs and nothing else from the page. I need to keep this script tag since I am using it to initialize a timer which outputs html/css code back.

Is there some way to get around this?

**EDIT - Works with async option set to true but now it doesn't analyze the script. Console log: Uncaught ReferenceError: Countdown is not defined**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
        options.async = true;
    });

     $(".navLink").click(function() {
        $.get( 'home.php', function( data ) {           
            $(".container").append(data);       
        });
     });     
});
```

Comment: `$('body').append(file)`

Comment: This would take care of the script?

Comment: Are there any errors in the javascript console of your browser? And by "tags" you just mean it has HTML tags and the other ones that work are just plaintext?

Comment: Nope, no errors in console. Yeah I only have this one <script> tag and the rest is simple html/css tags like divs, p, etc.

Comment: Actually, using other methods such as append and .html, I am getting this:

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having an issue understanding your question so I apologize if this comment isn't directly related. It would seem that `$.load` should work as you're expecting. I created two fiddles. One loads content from another fiddle (that contains tags as well as a script tag). The script executes fine (and calls a function in the parent, which also works fine): Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qzffp0xb/ - Another example using ajax (with an explicity dataType): http://jsfiddle.net/5jw93cyx/

Comment: The fiddle that both call is here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/n4vz7yh4/3/show/

Comment: Thanks Jack. Unlike before where it only shows the script tag, now I am able to properly view everything in the container except the script tag. Also I am getting this console error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Countdown is not defined

Check out my updated version of code

Comment: Any chance maybe a scoping issue for the function? Is `Countdown` a global or is it tucked away in a jQuery ready function (`$(function() { ... })` ??) Or maybe an `IIFE` ??

Comment: It is a global function

Comment: I have had this problem before, I ended up putting the scripts into a separate file and using `jQuery.getScript()` to include the scripts.